# How to get a list of all releases and release notes associated with a pipeline using Azure Rest API? Trying to connect Azure Devops to Power BI

Tags: json, azure-devops, powerbi, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am attempting to connect Power Bi and Azure Devops using Azure DevOps REST API. I have looked at the documentation a thousand times and I am still confused. I want to connect to a pipeline and show all releases associated with it and show the description of those releases. Documentation is confusing. Please help.

I can view all runs from the pipeline using the code below, but no descriptions.
https://dev.azure.com/Organization/Project/_apis/pipelines/pipelineid/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
I was thinking maybe start there, but no use.

Documentation states that the correct code to get a list of releases is:
https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0
But releases are not under a release tab, and just under the pipeline tab.

I am just confused and need some assistance on where the API endpoint URL is to get the release descriptions for a pipeline.

Comment: I am pretty sure with _release descriptions_ you mean the message of the associated commit of the release, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: You will find the commit id property `sourceVersion` of each release under `artifacts.definitionReference.sourceVersion` with the api call `$(collection)/$(project)/_apis/release/releases/$(releaseId)`. After that, you can get the *commit comment* with the [Get Commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) call over the rest api.

Comment: The call: 
$(collection)/$(project)/_apis/release/releases/$(releaseId)
fails and displays no page found.

I have the release ID, the correct authorization token, and everything. Yet that call doesn't work. The releases tab is under the pipeline tab dropdown. When I select releases, it displays all pipeline and the releases for each each one. There is no tab "release" with releases in it.